# Drag and drop game - why isn't it working now I've moved it to another domain?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

Earlier this year I did some work on a drag and drop game. It was the first thing I'd coded other than basic html. I got it working but then had to put it to one side for a while.

I've now come back to work on it. The game I had created was put on the ftp of a domain I no longer have. I took the html and image files and put them on another domain expecting them to work. However now nothing drags!

I don't know what could be different. I can barely remember how I coded this in the first place. Is there an additional file that should be on the ftp or something like that? Can anyone shed any light?

Game: http://www.vic-taylor.com/dolls/doll6.html

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable()
    });
    </script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#draggable2" ).draggable();
    });
    </script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#draggable3" ).draggable();
    });
    </script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#draggable4" ).draggable();
    });
    </script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#draggable5" ).draggable();
    });
    </script>


</head>
</body>

<div id="bodies/palepd.gif">
    <img src="bodies/palepd.gif" class="ui-widget-content" id="draggable">
    <img src="bodies/trousers.gif" class="ui-widget-content" id="draggable2">
<img src="bodies/top.gif" class="ui-widget-content" id="draggable3">
<img src="bodies/dress.gif" class="ui-widget-content" id="draggable4">
<img src="bodies/coat.gif" class="ui-widget-content" id="draggable5">
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: Just a warning to readers - link isn't necessarily 100% safe for work :)

Comment: should work on your new system as long as all files are still there do you get a specific error ?

Comment: Hey @Dukeatcoding thanks for your reply. No, no error, the clothing just wont drag and drop. The files I've put on the ftp are the .html file and the gifs of the clothing. I wasn't sure if there were any other files like jquery library files or something.

Comment: you tried chrome developer tools or something else to see whether there is an js error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, your HTML has this error:

`<div id="bodies/palepd.gif">`

I would suggest changing your code to reference an exact version of jquery, not just the latest version. This is because jquery and jquery-ui versions need to be compatible.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason the html was removed from my answer. The error is this: "<div id="bodies/palepd.gif">"

Comment: Thanks for the advice, how would I work out which version of jquery to state?

Comment: ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Basically, you probably wanted a name, not a URL, as the id.

Comment: Well, you need to look up the version of jquery-ui you are using, and find out what versions of jquery it supports.

I can't tell if this will solve the error, but it will prevent things from breaking in the future anyway so its a good idea.

Comment: Sorry can you explain what the problem with that is, I am new to coding.

Comment: see how it says <div id="bodies/palepd.gif"> ?

The id is only allowed to be letters, numbers, hyphens, underscores, colons and dots. But it looks like you intended to have a URL to a picture palepd.gif. The ID is not for an image url, the ID is a name used in your code to refer to the HTML tag you have written.

Comment: Just changed the jquery ui version specified to the latest version (1.9) and it now works! Thank you so much for your help fabspro. You're a life saver. Does this now mean I have to continually change the ui version specified each time a new version comes out?

Comment: You can keep with the old version and it will keep working unless a new web browser breaks it all. Until then, it's happy sailing :)